# jspm registry create without prompt

Tags: jspm

To add a custom git source as a JSPM registry, it seems the only option is to run the following at the command line :

```
jspm registry create mySource jspm-git
```

At which point you get prompted to enter the source url, ssh://git@whatever.com. How can I do this in a single command, without the prompt? This would be pretty useful for automated, unattended builds. Better still, can registries be defined directly in a project's package.json file, as part of the local jspm config?

Comment: Were you able to figure anything out? I'm looking to do essentially the exact same thing and haven't found any solutions. There's [an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/190) that sounds like it would be the solution, but it hasn't had any activity in a year.

Comment: No, afraid I still haven't figured this out, though I guess it's worth moving this to that ticket to see if we can bump it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/431

All you need to do is add the " -y" switch at the end of your statement, for example,

```
jspm registry create bower jspm-bower-endpoint -y
```

will add bower without prompting you. Confirmed working on Linux and Windows 10, I'm not sure if it's a bash convention, so it might not work on older version of Windows.

UPDATE :

The answer above is wrong, I muddled the git and bower endpoint handlers. To properly register bitbucket from script, use

```
jspm config registries.bitbucket.remote https://bitbucket.org
jspm config registries.bitbucket.baseurl https://bitbucket.org
jspm config registries.bitbucket.handler jspm-git
```